# amchart generating a column chart(with three items), need to be grouped by month

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am using Amcharts, for generating 3 columns for every month, I tried many attempts, but it didn't come properly.
There are 3 columns, which all should be generated on a monthly basis. For example, for July, all these should be plotted, likewise for August and September and so on.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0rd2cs3/30/) . Not sure what I am missing here. I am trying something like :  [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0rd2cs3/31/)

```
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "startDuration": 2,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 2,
    "color": "#FF6600"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 5,
    "color": "#FCD202"
  },{
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 9,
    "color": "#0D8ECF"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Visitors"
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "colorField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0.1,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "depth3D": 20,
  "angle": 30,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 90
  },
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "clickGraphItem",
    "method": function(event) {
      alert(event.item.category);
    }
  }]
});
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I cannot see any time data field in your data in the fiddle

Comment: I have editted with the fiddle link with the data , with which I am trying. Please refer above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying for what data you need to plot bars. You need to include the columns you want to plot in the `graphs` field of your data

ex:

```
"graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "colorField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0.1,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "europe"
}]
```